# Mi videojuego programado en Visual Studio 2019 C++ no se ejecuta en otra computadora

Tags: c++

por favor quisiera que me ayuden porque tengo problemas al ejecutar el código de mi videojuego en otra computadora.

Resulta que he programado un videojuego que se ejecuta de forma correcta en mi computadora utilizando la configuración de modo release y plataforma x86 y también en la opción donde dice biblioteca en tiempo de ejecución lo configuré en DLL de depuración multiproceso(/MDd).

De esta forma el videojuego se ejecuta correctamente en mi computadora, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto en otra computadora me sale el mensaje de error

> "La aplicación no se pudo iniciar correctamente (0xc000007b). Haga clic en Aceptar para cerrarla".

He visto videos y artículo con varias formas de arreglar el problema, pero nada, no he podido solucionarlo. Luego probé utilizando la configuración de modo release y plataforma x86 pero esta vez en la opción donde dice biblioteca en tiempo de ejecución lo configuré en DLL multiproceso(/MD). De esta forma mi videojuego si se ejecuta en mi computadora, sin embargo se cuelga y no funciona de forma correcta.
De la misma forma cuando lo instalé en otra computadora, esta vez si pudo ejecutarse con normalidad solo que presenta los mismo errores que cuando la ejecuto en mi computadora.

Estoy tratando de resolverlo de la primera forma configurandolo en DLL de depuracion multiproceso porque mi programa funciona perfectamente en mi computadora. De la segunda forma no he podido hallar los problemas con el código.

Por favor les pediría puedan ayudarme porque me siento desesperado ya que estoy tratando de resolver el problema desde hace una semana. Muchas gracias y espero su comprensión.

Comment: intenta algo de esto ya me paso: https://pcseguro.es/preguntenos/como-solucionar-el-codigo-de-error-0xc000007b-en-windows-10/

Comment: As creado un juego de ese nivel y no as aprendido a debuggear? Y pides ayuda sin un codigi fuente que analizar  buena suerte campeon!

Comment: @Bryro yo considero que en lugar de simplemente decir que tiene una "mala" pregunta sería mejor que leyeras el [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) ya que tu comentario puede tomarse como ofensa, y tambien ayudaría si le pasamos los links de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ya estoy empezando a creer que estas preguntas son de spam. Ya es la 3ra o 4ta que veo en la que no hay codigo, no se describe mucho, y la unica descripcion es: "Funciona en mi maquina, y en la otra no", y la solucion es no colocar nada de debug. Si tu codigo falla en un release, y en debug no, o si falla alugnas veces si, y otras no, estas cayendo en comportamiento indefinido en algun punto. Esa es la respuesta mas completa que se puede dar sin que compartas el codigo.

Comment: Googleando el error en 2 minutos he averiguado que puede ser un problema de usar una dll de 64 bits en una aplicación de 32 bits, o bien una dll ausente, usa un [explorador de dependencias](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) para averiguarlo.